Proposal for a 2024 room owner election for The Nineteenth Byte
Currently, The Nineteenth Byte (CGCC's main chat room) has seven room owners, who are responsible for certain moderation actions, including pinning messages, clearing stars, and maintaining feeds. This list hasn't grown in over two years (in fact, it's shrunk), so I brought up the idea of doing another RO election, which was well received. I suggested a different mechanism from our previous elections, in which there would not be a limit to the number of users elected, and instead just a threshold.
This suggested mechanism would work as follows:

Candidates would submit their bio as an answer to a combined nominations/voting post
Any candidate who receives a 3:1 upvote:downvote ratio and at least 10 upvotes becomes an RO, subject to approval by the current mods/ROs

So, there are roughly three options:

No RO election, keep things as they are
Do a normal RO election with N candidates
Do an election with a threshold instead of a limited number of candidates

Should we move forward with this?

Yes, with the suggested mechanism
Too many ROs is almost never an issue, and I have a lot of trust in most of the regulars in TNB. Choosing a fixed number of candidates makes things unnecessarily competitive, and runs the risk of excluding a qualified candidate (or including an unserious one, if we choose too high of a number).

Yes.
I see no problem with this, so yeah. But detail the process more in the voting post.

An answer like this has already been posted I believe.

Yes I know but consensus is a good thing and I also say to clarify it.

You could post a comment to the question instead. You can express consent by upvoting rydwolf's answer.

Well I don't say, with the suggested mechanism. Just that generically an election is good. Me upvoting Rydwold's post would be endorsing the mechanism.
